# Ruby: Check for Byte Order Marker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, byte-order-mark

In Rails, we are some text files as ISO-8859-1. Sometimes the files come in as `UTF-8 with BOM`. I am trying to determine if its `UTF-8 with BMO` then re-read the file as `bom|UTF-8`.

I trying the following but it doesn't seem to compare correctly:

```
# file is saved as UTF-8 with BOM using Sublime Text 2

> string = File.read(file, encoding: 'ISO-8859-1')

# this doesn't work, while it supposed to work
> string.start_with?("\xef\xbb\xbf".force_encoding("UTF-8"))
> false

# it works if I try this
> string.start_with?('ï»¿')
> true
```

The purpose is to read the file as `UTF-8 with BOM` if file has the Byte Order Marker at the start and I want to avoid `string.start_with?('ï»¿')` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string.start_with?("\u00ef\u00bb\u00bf")
```

From [Ruby official documentation](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/doc/syntax/literals.rdoc#strings):

> `\xnn`      hexadecimal bit pattern, where nn is 1-2 hexadecimal digits ([0-9a-fA-F])
>
> `\unnnn`  Unicode character, where nnnn is exactly 4 hexadecimal digits ([0-9a-fA-F])

That said, to interpolate a unicode character, one should use `\uXXXX` notation. It is safe and we can reliable use this version.

Comment: Thank you @mudasobwa. It works. Would you mind explaining a bit that why `HEX` version was not working your version is working? Can we reliably use the this version and confident that it will always work? Just trying to understand it.

Answer (score 2):

This didn't work for me, I had to check the bytes.

```rb
string[0].bytes ==  [239, 187, 191] # true for UTF-8 + BOM
```

[See BOM for other encodings](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark)

If you just want to check the file, and reopen it properly (e.g. `File.open(file, "r:bom|utf-8")`).

Then you don't need the whole file, just read the 3 first bytes

```rb
is_bom = File.open(file) { |f| f.read(3).bytes ==  [239, 187, 191] }
```